# Debian Jessie / Xfce4: hp-systray[PID]: error: option -s not recognized

Tags: debian, xfce, hplip

Debian Jessie, Xfce4 ver. 4.10, HPLIP ver. 3.14.6

After upgrading from Debian Wheezy to Jessie (yeah, I know...), started getting the following (level 1/alert) notice in the boot logs:

```
hp-systray[PID]: error: option -s not recognized
```

Closer scrutiny of the subject log entry revealed that the command `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/hp-systray -session ....` had been attempted at some point during the login process. Running said command in a terminal does indeed produce the subject error squawk. Turns out that `-session` is not a valid switch for this command...

Never saw said notice when running Wheezy.

Internet research yielded the observation that this problem seems to be relatively rare, seemingly innocuous, has been around for at least 10 years, and has never been explained.

I have noticed that, if I kill the `hp-systray` process before shutdown, the problem is not there upon the subsequent boot, but will return for any follow-on boot not preceded by said "kill" operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some experimenting revealed that the subject log squawk is related to a line in the `~/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-$HOSTNAME:0` file that was referenced by the Xfce4 session manager upon login (the line that follows this is reproduced here for clarity):

```
Client6_RestartCommand=/usr/bin/hp-systray,-session,23775cb5c-d4da-45ef-9d25-410c10c6a78b_1597436809_471656
Client6_Program=/usr/bin/hp-systray
```

Apparently, said session manager is including the `hp-systray` process into the data it saves in order to preserve the session. I still have some machines with similar package suites running Wheezy and have discovered that process is never saved by the session manager on them. But, the session manager DOES save said process under Jessie, with less than desirable results.

It sure would be nice if the user were given a way to exclude particular processes from being preserved by the Xfce4 session manager...

Meanwhile, I've cobbled together an inelegant, but effective workaround.

I've written a minimal service file, named `stop_the_madness.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Digger add, prevents hp-systray log alert on next boot
After=syslog.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/\/usr\/bin\/hp-systray/\/bin\/true/g;s/-session//' /home/$USER/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-$HOSTNAME:0"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Place said newly created service file into the `/etc/systemd/system` directory, then `chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/stop_the_madness.service`. I then did a `systemctl daemon-reload`, followed by `systemctl enable stop_the_madness.service`

From now on, by the time the boot process reaches login, the offending line in the offending `~/.cache/xfce4-session-$HOSTNAME:0` file looks like (with the following line):

```
Client6_RestartCommand=/bin/true,,2ba711268-faee-473f-a6ce-dfb1efcff056_1597378561_935995
Client6_Program=/bin/true
```

End of problem (for reboots, shutdowns and halts, anyway).

**UPDATE:** After upgrading to Debian Stretch, I started seeing the following bootlog warning: `...Invalid escape sequences in line, correcting:...` (not sure if this warning was being thrown under Jessie). As seen in [Stop systemd from flooding logs with "Ignoring unknown escape sequence"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/656148/144299), I merely replaced (in the "ExecStart" line) all single-backslash escapes with double-backslash escapes:

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/\\/usr\\/bin\\/hp-systray/\\/bin\\/true/g;s/-session//' /home/dg/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-2011:0"`

End of problem.