# Stop systemd from flooding logs with "Ignoring unknown escape sequence"

Tags: systemd, regular-expression, escape-characters, syslog

This is my service

```
[Unit]
Description=Cleanup service I made

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/me/scripts/cleanup.sh -d /home/me/scripts/testfolder/ -f ".*/*.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*.log"
User=root
Group=root
```

The service runs, but my logs are getting FLOODED with

`/lib/systemd/system/cleanup.service:5: Ignoring unknown escape sequences: ".*/*.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*.log"`

I have tested the script, I know it works. And I know it works in crontab as well.

**What I tried:**

- Tried putting everything in double quotes
- Changed ExecStart to "/bin/bash -c ""
- Tried using the systemd-escape chars for directory path (replacing "/" with "-"). However this is for paths not the regex.

That entry is a regex, I cant really change its entry. Do I need to escape in a different way? Or simpler, how do I tell systemd to ignore the problem and stop dumping "Ignoring unknown sequences" into syslog. Just run the script as is?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/23935637/10622916 or https://serverfault.com/q/694151 (Found by searching for `systemd Ignoring unknown escape sequences`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape each backslash with another backslash.

```
... ".*/*.[0-9]\\{4\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}- ...
```

See `man systemd.service` section *COMMAND LINES*, or in more recent versions [systemd.syntax](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html).

Comment: This worked! I thought that would affected my regex, but it seems systemd parsed it properly.